# How to mock HashMap values in mockito without using spring

Tags: java, junit, hashmap

I want to write a JUnit test to execute a method that accepts a single parameter and a condition, based on the hashmap key.

I have a class, say ClassA. There is a method in ClassA, say MethodB. 
MethodB accepts a String parameter.

Assume that type of `field` is `HashMap<string, string>` and it has a values `<"first", "last">`.

I pass value1 as "first".

```
public String MethodB(String value1) throws Exception {
  if (field.containsKey(value1)) {
    object tempobject;
    tempobject = field.get(value1);
    //next step processing
  } else {
    //come out of the method without processing.
  }
}
```

How to mock `field.containsKey` to "first" with key value as "last" and also call the MethodB with parameter value as "first", so if `field.containsKey(value1)` is true, then proceeds to the next steps.

Comment: is that field injected through constructor?

Comment: Nope.. HashMap  "field"  is initialized in a different  method within ClassA. In production scenario,  field.containskey will have a value before executing methodB.. I just want" if(field.containskey(value1)" to be mocked to true

Comment: Well, you can use reflection to inject a mock HashMap to that field, since it is not parametrized through anything.